# GPU render cycles

Tags: gpu

My laptop didn't use my GPU for renderen in cycles. What can I do. Which settings do I have to swich? 
I had tried to switch the setting but nothing works. I have downloaded cuda but I don't knpw what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

If it's supported by Blender you need to enable it in the user preferences. By default the render device is your CPU.